# Java Swing GUI Interfering with Encryption/Decryption

Tags: java, swing, encryption, rsa

I’m working on a small java app to demonstrate to some students the concept of public key encryption using an implementation of the RSA algorithm. It might be worth mentioning that I am not using Java’s libraries, as that would abstract most of the key concepts.

The algorithm I use for encryption just breaks up strings into an array of characters, encrypts each character, and then displays each encrypted character on its own line (for readability). I understand that this is not secure for practical purposes; padding algorithms are the subject of a later lesson.

The problem I’m running into is that encryption/decryption works fine when the encrypted output is not taken from an input box in the GUI. For example, this code would work:

```
String sample = “Hello World”;
BigInteger[] encrypted = RsaExample.encrypt(sample);
For (BigInteger b : encrypted) {
    System.out.print(b.toString() + “\n”);
String decrypted = RsaExample.decrypt(encrypted); //Returns “Hello World”
```

However, when I use the GUI to accomplish the same task the result is mangled:

```
//When “Encrypt” button is pressed
String sample = InputBox.getText();
BigInteger[] encrypted = RsaExample.encrypt(sample);
String output;
For (BigInteger b : encrypted) {
    output += (b.toString() + “\n”);
OutputBox.setText(output);


//When “Decrypt” button is pressed
String encrypted = OutputBox.getText();
BigInteger[] encrypted_arr = encrypted.split(“\n”);
String decrypted = RsaExample.decrypt(encrypted_arr);
OutputBox.setText(decrypted);
```

I’ve confirmed (by copying/pasting the output to a document) that the output is being formatted with newlines. I suspect that the problem is from the GUI adding some sort of spacing or somehow mangling the exact output.

EDIT: Here is the exact code from each ActionPerformed method:

```
 private void buttonEncryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String input = fieldInput.getText();
    BigInteger[] encrypted = encrypt.encrypt(input);
    String output = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < encrypted.length; i++) {
        //String concatenation seems to fail here
        output += encrypted[i].toString() + "\n";
    }
    System.out.println(output);
    fieldOutput.setText(output);
}                                             

private void buttonDecryptActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    String input = fieldOutput.getText();
    input = input.trim();
    fieldInput.setText(input);
    fieldOutput.setText(""); //Clear the output
    String[] chars = input.split("\n");
    System.out.print(chars.length);
    BigInteger[] encrypted = new BigInteger[chars.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        //Remove Whitespace that caused NumberFormatException            
        String trimmed = chars[i].replaceAll("\\s",""); 
        encrypted[i] = new BigInteger(trimmed);
    }
    String decrypted = encrypt.decrypt(encrypted);
    fieldOutput.setText(decrypted);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  As an aside, that code is not only uncompilable because it is code snippets, but also because of incorrect case used in Java keywords.

Comment: Agree with @AndrewThompson. I think that you've got a bug in the Swing code that you're not showing us. The JTextComponents should not be putting in any formatting anything.

Comment: And if you want to see what text is being returned, then why not simply change the String returned into a char array, and then iterate through array, printing out the int value of each char. `for (char c : textarea.getText().toCharArray()) { System.out.println("" + (int)c);}`

Comment: From where does the whitespaces causing the NumberFormatException comes from? and is it really \\s you should replace? (not just \s)?

Comment: It was a single space being appended to the very end of the encrypted data. Would \s$ be a better substitution?